# How do you aggregate the delta of values between two arbitrary datetime columns?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, window-functions

Please look at the columns and types of a table called `History`:

```
- id PRIMARY KEY 
- account_id STRING
- total_spent FLOAT
- date_created DATETIME
```

Sample data for this table:

```
(id, account_id, total_spent, date_created)
(1, '123-456-7890', 10, 2018-10-01 00:00:00+08)
(2, '123-456-7890', 20, 2018-10-02 00:00:00+08)
(3, '123-456-7890', 30, 2018-10-04 00:00:00+08)
```

---

If I have to find out the money spent by account `123-456-7890` between `2018-10-01 00:00:01+08` and `2018-10-02 00:00:01+08`:

1. let A = the latest total_spent before `2018-10-01 00:00:01+08`
2. let B = the latest total_spent before `2018-10-02 00:00:01+08`
3. Subtract B - A = 10.

---

If I have to find the amount of money spent by account `123-456-7890` between `2018-10-03 00:00:01+08` and `2018-10-04 00:00:01+08`:

1. A will be 20 since that is the **latest** row before `2018-10-03 00:00:01+08`
2. B will be 30
3. Thus answer is 10 as well.

---

### Questions:

1. Given this schema, how do you calculate the total amount of money spent by all accounts between two datetime?
2. If I am interested to calculate spending for accounts between two arbitrary datetime, how can I restructure my schema to make my life easier?

Comment: `STRING`, `DATETIME` are not valid Postgres data types. Please provide the actual `CREATE TABLE` statement showing data types and constraints. And always your version of Postgres. `SELECT version();` helps.